# TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bit trouble with my VueJS app. What I want is to send request to server on load, that responses me "username" of my user and update it on my website. Everything works fine, but when I try to assigned retured value, my program stops loading images and error from title appears in console. Value from server is correct - checked by console.
Here is my code for displaying username :

```
<span class="iconsNav" style="margin-left: 4px" >{{this.username}}</span>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script>
//components
export default {
  methods : {
    login(){
      //function to login
    },
    async getUserData(){
      var token = 'Token '+ VueCookie.get('access_token')
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/account/data',{
        headers:{
          'Authorization': token
        }
        })

        console.log(response.data.username)
        //when i try execute this line error occurs
        this.username = response.data.username
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {
      username : "User"
    }
},
mounted: function(){
  this.getUserData()
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<span class="iconsNav" style="margin-left: 4px" >{{username}}</span>
```

To get data in vue, you don't need `this`.